# How to add an attribute to repeater item at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, addattribute

I have a repeater and i want to add a mouse over attribute to its items.

Is it possible to add attributes at run-time, if yes then how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
     <HeaderTemplate>
          <table>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr runat="server" id="itemRow">
               <td>
                    <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>
               </td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
          </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Item.FindControl("itemRow") as HtmlTableRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = string.Format("alert('Hello from row #{0}');", e.Item.ItemIndex );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir. I have lost 12 points to get this answer. lolz.. thanks once again.

Comment: How can this one work? FindControl only return 1 control. And we should not use the same ID for multiple elements. Instead we can set HTML attribute directly: onmouseover="<% ... %>"