# how to redirect to another page while click on item of a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and i have made it click able using code from [How to add an attribute to repeater item at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963357/how-to-add-attribute-on-item-of-repeater-at-runtime/7964174#7964174)

Now i want when i click on any item of repeater it will redirect to another page along with query string.. whose value comes from database like (userid). Actually what i want to do when i click on any item i want to redirect to user detail-page along with its user information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add another attribute to the itemRow ;):

```
row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("window.location = '{0}';", ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/Default.aspx?userId={0}", e.Item.DataItem)) );
```

Instead to using `e.Item.DataItem` you may cast DataItem to concrete class and use that class property like this:

```
MyClass mc = e.Item.DataItem as MyClass;
row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("window.location = '{0}';", ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/Default.aspx?userId={0}", mc.UserId)) );
```

Generally, you may add attributes on row in repeater's ItemTemplate without server-side code. All that you need it's just to bind appropriate fields from your datasource to attributes:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <tr onmouseover="window.document.title = '<%# Eval("userId", "Click to navigate onto user {0} details page.") %>'"
         onclick='window.location = "<%# ResolveClientUrl( "~/Default.aspx?userId=" + Eval("userid") ) %>"'>
          <td>
               <%# Eval("UserId") %>
          </td>
     </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Since it's your application, I haven't any idea about where from you can get the userid

Comment: thank u very much sir i have got what i required thanks alot. once again